# Compound functions question

Tags: functions

[image]

Can someone help me understand the answer?

The mark scheme says $g(x)=0$ or $3$

$x=-1$ or $4$ or $1$ or $2$

From my understanding, $y=g(x)=3$ when $g(x)$ is $1$ or $2$. Is that where the 1 and 2 in the x= line comes from? The 0 and 3 in the first line of the mark scheme is from where $y=f(x)=3$, the x values at which that happens. Why does the mark scheme say g(x)=0 and 3 then?

If someone could explain all of this to me, I'd really appreciate it.